# calcular potencias negativas en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando calcular la potencia de un número sin el uso de la función pow. Hice los tres casos que se pueden presentar, pero cuando el exponente = 0 no me imprime nada, y cuando el exponente < 0 me imprime siempre 0. No sé qué error pueda tener en mi código. Muchas gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void pedirDatos();
int funpot();

int numero,exponente;
int q=1;
int q2=1;
int main(){
    pedirDatos();
    funpot();
return 0;
}

void pedirDatos(){
    printf ("Digite el numero a elevar: ");
    scanf ("%i",&numero);
    printf ("Digite el exponente de elevacion: ");
    scanf ("%i",&exponente);
}

int funpot(){
    if(exponente==0)
    return 1;
    else if(exponente>0){
        for(int i=1;i<=exponente;i++)
            {
            q=q*numero;       
            }
            printf("El resultado de la elevacion es: \n%d",q);;
    }
        else if(exponente<0){
            for(int i=1;i<=exponente;i++)
                {
                q2=1/(q2*numero); 
                }
                printf ("El resultado de la elevacion es: \n%d",q2=1/(q2*numero));
    return q2;
    }       
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> cuando el exponente = 0 no me imprime nada

Lógico, cuando el exponente es 0 te limitas a devolver `1`:

```
if(exponente==0)
    return 1;
```

> cuando el exponente < 0 me imprime siempre 0

```
else if(exponente<0){
    for(int i=1;i<=exponente;i++)
```

Algo esperable viendo tu código, si `exponente < 0` e `i=1`, está claro que `exponente<i` desde el principio, luego el bucle no se va a ejecutar ni una sola vez

Tu función hace aguas por varios motivos:

1. No usas parámetros sino variables globales. No es un buen planteamiento. Es facil que acabes creando variables locales con el mismo nombre, con lo que ocultarías las variables globales y el programa no funcionaría como esperas o, ¿Cómo controlarías la modificación de las variables en un entorno multihilo?
2. La función hace uso de la consola. No crees acoplamientos innecesarios. Es preferible llamar a `cout` (no `printf`, que esa función es heredada de C) con el resultado de la invocación de tu función:

   ```
    int resultado = funpot(10, 5);
    std::cout << "El resultado es " << resultado;
   ```
3. ¿Qué pinta esa llamada a `getch` en la función? Está en el sitio perfecto para que olvides su existencia y luego pierdas media hora intentando entender por qué el código se queda esperando que pulses una tecla.
4. La función **no retorna nada** cuando `exponente>0`
5. El tabulado es horrible, eso hace que la función sea difícil de leer
6. Los exponentes negativos suelen generar números con decimales, el tipo `int` no es capaz de almacenar decimales, luego perderás muchísima precisión.
7. La lógica del cálculo del exponente negativo es errónea. Debes calcular `q2` como si el exponente fuese positivo y después hacer la división `1/q2`

Adicionalmente, date cuenta que **el último else no precisa de un if**

Solo se pueden dar tres casos:

- Exponente mayor que 0
- Exponente igual a 0
- Exponente menor que 0

Es obvio pensar, por tanto, que si el exponente no es mayor que 0 ni tampoco es igual a 0, entonces, necesariamente, debe ser menor que 0. El último `if` es totalmente innecesario.

No añadas condiciones innecesarias. Lo único que conseguirás es que el código sea más complicado de mantener

```
if(exponente==0)
    // ...
else if(exponente>0)
    // ...
else
    // ...
```

Tu función corregida:

```
double funpot(int base, int exponente)
{
    double toReturn = 1;
    if (exponente > 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<exponente; i++)
            toReturn *= base;
    }
    else if (exponente < 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i>exponente; i--)
            toReturn *= base;
       toReturn = 1/toReturn;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

O también:

```
double funpot(int base, int exponente)
{
    double toReturn = 1;

    if (exponente != 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<std::abs(exponente); i++)
            toReturn *= base;

        if (exponente < 0)
            toReturn = 1/toReturn;
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por aclararme todos esos puntos, ya lo arreglé y funcionó correctamente. También muchas gracias por los consejos, me han servido bastante para aprender e ir mejorando.